# Multi-textured Terrain?

Tags: c++, directx, terrain

How would I accomplish multi-textured terrain? I need to know how to write the HLSL shader for it. The world already UV maps itself and I can get it to do 1 texture at a time. But I want more than 1 texture being displayed on my screen.

Here is my vertex declaration.

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 Decl[] =
    {
        {
            0,
            0,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION,
            0
        },
        {
            0,
            0,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,
            0
        },
        {
            0,
            0,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,
            1
        },
        D3DDECL_END()
    };
```

I am also using D3DFVF_XYZ and D3DFVF_TEX2

My variables for for each vertex are X, Y, Z, U1, V1, W1, U2, V2, W2

Comment: Have a look at [texture splatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_splatting). While normally used for texture blending, you can easily adapt it for sharp texture transition over large areas, with low res alpha maps.

Comment: problem is that my lands size is so big that its 128000x128000.. i cant store an image that big

Comment: With that size you'll probably need to chunk anyway, so one image per chunk might be an option. Or if you want really large areas a 4kx4k 1 channel alpha texture could do, although that might look shitty.

Comment: I managed to load the whole world up without chunking. I made my self a whole engine from scratch so it can do a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle multitexturing is as simple as performing multiple texture fetches in the pixel shader and then blending the two colors together using some formula (average, min, max, etc).

For greatest control you can use multiple UV coordinates (using TEXCOORD0, TEXCOORD1, etc) and having multiple textures set to the effect, but you can also use a single UV coordinate and simply scale it when working with terrain, especially if you generate the terrain.

A quick search on "hlsl multitexturing" gave me [this tutorial](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut17.html) which might be a good start for you.

---

> I need it so that 1 part of my terrain has a certain texture and the
>   only part needs a completely different texture. Not mixing 2 textures
>   together.

Assuming your textures are both 128x128 what you can do is make a new image that is 256x128 (or 256x256), copy your first texture into the (top) left part of the new image, and the second texture into the right part.

Now you modify your UV coordinates on the mesh, the parts that want the first texture get their U halved (so it goes into the left part of the 256x128 texture) and the ones that want the second texture are halved and get 0.5 added (so it goes into the right part of the combined texture).

Your terrain should now render with 2 textures. You may notice some artefacts where you go from one to the other texture, this can be fixed by duplicating the vertices at the seam, so that the triangle that wants the left texture does not share any vertices with the triangle that want the right texture.

This wouldn't be referred to as multitexturing, seeing as how your only using one texture (which just happens to be a texturemap with multiple textures in it).

**To solve it with actual multitexturing** you would use two Vector3 UV coordinates, the z component would be used for weight, two textures (which can be your original two textures) and then a hlsl pixel shader that blends the two.

Since you can chose the weight of both textures you can chose to make a quick transition by changing z from 0 to 1 and vice versa for the second texture. This option has the benefit of allowing you to slowly blend textures in places when you want to, but the drawback of requiring a special shader which does twice the work of the single texture one (in terms of texture fetches).

```
float4 col1 = tex2d(texture1, uv1.xy)
float4 col2 = tex2d(texture2, uv2.xy)

float4 color = (col1 * uv1.z) + (col2 * uv2.z) / (uv1.z + uv2.z)
```

**You can also split the mesh** into multiple parts, this allows you to use the same textures as in the multitexturing version, with the same shader as in the single texture version. But requires two draw calls instead of a single draw call.

Simply go through each vertex and if it needs the first texture, add it to the first mesh, and if it needs the second vertex, add it to the second mesh. Make sure that the edge vertices, between the two textures, are duplicated so that you do not get any holes in your terrain.

This is the simplest option, but making a texturemap would have better performance and multitexturing would be more flexible (such as going from all grass to gravel can be done smoothly instead of having a sharp line, where you chose to do so)

Comment: You are close to what I am talking about. But not really. I need it so that 1 part of my terrain has a certain texture and the only part needs a completely different texture. Not mixing 2 textures together.

Comment: I have 2 TEXCOORDs but now I need it so the color.out variable in the pixel shader can display both of the textures that are being referenced using sampler2D

Comment: The "normal" way to solve that would be to either make a texture with both textures in it, thus one UV can pick between the two textures, think a character model texture where face/clothing/eyes are stored in the same texture but at different coordinates in the texture. The other "normal" option is to split the terrain into two meshes, that way you can set the texture for each mesh separately. With multitexturing you can provide a weight with the texcoord, use a vector4 with w being the weight, this way you can both blend and do quick swaps between textures as you need

Comment: well the first was is what i have been attempting for days and its not working right and just doesn't seem worth it anymore. The second way was the better way I was looking at. Do you have any suggestions on how the code for that would look?

Comment: @dvds414 I edited my answer, it was getting too much for comments

Comment: This answer sounds better. I am going to go try it

Comment: Sadly this isn't working :/ It turned my whole world gray.

(http://gyazo.com/419eefc0cf548bc962a210b20e3b30fe) I think it might have to do with my D3DFVF? its current set to D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX2 and my declaration is long so I will post it in question

Comment: @dvds414 Which version did you try to implement, I would recommend you take a step back to your working version, and then step by step add a feature and test it. In particular, if you want to add another UV then first add it into the D3DFVF and vertice format, making sure that it continues to render without any further changes. Extra information that the shader doesn't use will be ignored (AFAIK). The absolutely simplest would be to change the texture and UV's since that won't require any actual code changes from your working version.

Comment: I got it to work as i changed the FVF and the shader code and then when I tried to make it so there was weight it never worked so I threw away that idea and tried a bunch of new things and none of them worked. From my research, doing texture weights seems to be the smartest but for some reason it does not want to work

Comment: If I do your code but change it so the output of the shader is just Col1 it works fine, but only displays one texture (obviously). http://gyazo.com/e91a42cadc8b636f5578c5392c29cf4a now I need it so both textures work at once. I am able to switch between the 2 textures by making it output Col2 so I know both textures work. A good question I have is how does my program know which letters are the position? I have it so its X, Y, Z.. but how does the progrma know that is the position? and my TEXCOORD1 is set to U and V.. how does it know that the U and V are supposed to be texturecoordinates?

Comment: Mostly, it doesn't. Texcoord1 can be up to a vector4x4 I believe and all it knows is how to interpolate the values before sending it to the shader, the exact meaning of the values are unknown to it, its your code that makes sense out of it. Im afraid I dont know how to change Texcoord1 to a Vector3 in C++, but you do need to describe the vertex structure to the graphicscard so it knows how many bytes are to be sent to the shader per vertice